# Getting too frequent location updates in the background

Tags: android, background, location, location-provider, fusedlocationproviderapi

In my app I am using ReactiveLocationProvider to get background location updates. (library [link](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation)) When my app is minimised (enters onPause) it starts receiving updates. It works fine, but the problem is I don't want that frequent updates. For example, in my code I have a LocationRequest that is **supposed** to get location update (one) when the user moves 1km and at least 10 minutes (setFastestInterval) have passed. According to my log, I am receiving more updates than needed. Anyone knows why?

this is my code in my MainActivity on create method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
LocationRequest request;
ReactiveLocationProvider locationProvider;
Subscription subscription;
Subscription onlyFirstTimeSubscription;
NotAbleToGetWeatherDataTask mNotAbleToGetWeatherDataTask = new NotAbleToGetWeatherDataTask();
int numOfBackgroundUpdates = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //-----------MY CODE STARTS HERE-----------------
    request = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
            .setSmallestDisplacement(1000)
            .setFastestInterval(10 * 1000)
            .setInterval(30 * 60 * 1000);
    locationProvider = new ReactiveLocationProvider(this);
}
```

and my onPause method:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //subscribe for background location updates...
    subscription = locationProvider.getUpdatedLocation(request)
            .subscribe(new Action1<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Location location) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Getting Background updates...");
                    MainActivity.this.latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    MainActivity.this.longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    numOfBackgroundUpdates++;

                }
            });
}
```

and I am unsubscribing from the request on destroy:

```
   @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "OnDestroy Called!");
    subscription.unsubscribe();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

recent log (I have moved 1km and at least 10minutes have passed)

```
12-28 17:12:25.564 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background  updates...
12-28 17:16:06.918 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:06.924 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:06.925 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:06.927 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:06.928 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:06.930 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:06.931 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:06.940 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:06.942 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:06.942 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:06.946 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:06.949 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:06.951 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:06.951 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:06.951 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
12-28 17:16:40.371 29845-29845/? D/MainActivity: Getting Background updates...
```

Comment: any chance you did register more than one request ?

Comment: I have, but I am unregistering it immediately when I get the location like that: LocationRequest oneTimeOnStartRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
  ...
                    @Override
                    public void call(Location location) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Getting first location updates...");
                        ..
                        onlyFirstTimeSubscription.unsubscribe();

                    }
                });

Comment: Do a gist with the complete code, please

Comment: Here@Blackbelt   https://github.com/boggogo/Stormy/blob/master/app/src/main/java/koemdzhiev/com/stormy/ui/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly adjust this:
Your  `setFastestInterval` in ms is `10 * 1000` -->
For 10 minutes you need to make this: `60 * 10 * 1000`

Then have a look at this:
You need to create one instance of your location provider class for the duration of your app:

If you look at [these links](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation) to the [ReaciveLocationProvider](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/pl/charmas/android/reactivelocation/sample/GeofenceActivity.java) You'll see passing the current context as a parameter.

```
ReactiveLocationProvider locationProvider = new ReactiveLocationProvider(context);
locationProvider.getLastKnownLocation()
.subscribe(new Action1<Location>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Location location) {
        doSthImportantWithObtainedLocation(location);
    }
});

reactiveLocationProvider = new ReactiveLocationProvider(this);
```

The author is passing the context as a parameter. I suggest you go through all your instances of the `reactiveLocationProvider` and create a single instance.

So create a static final context, using getapplicationcontext, or a similar method as suggested below.

example: *(this is taken from my library*

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(_CONTEXT);
```

Example in my custom class I pass a final context:

```
public class LocFinder extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private final Context mContext;

    public LocFinder(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }
```

Without examining the github code more thoroughly it's hard to say whether the author has safe guarded against this, but if you are calling it from MainActivity in oncreate like that, then you could be creating a new request.

```
  request = LocationRequest.create()
```

You are also asking for the location on OnPause:

```
MainActivity.this.latitude = location.getLatitude();
MainActivity.this.longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

I'm not 100% clear on the need for doing this.

Also make note of the original author's use of [`final`](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/pl/charmas/android/reactivelocation/sample/MainActivity.java) when creating a locationrequest. Which supports the idea of controlling your request calls for the lifetime of the app.

Shout out if you need more help.

Comment: I am not using the locationManager. It is there just to use its method to check if the location service is enabled. I am using the ReactiveLocationProvider library for my location updates/requests

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will definitely try making the request final. I am thinking of including this in the onPause method above the creation of the subscription of background updates like that: if(subscription != null) {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        } 
It will unsubscribe the previous subscription bevore creating a new one. On theory should work.